# How to pass into spring-boot context application properties location programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using java-main and injected inside Spring-boot container.
I am using Spring boot application properties configuration this way:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mycompany")
@PropertySource("file:/Users/tt/application.properties")
public class SpringConfiguration {
..
}
```

That works fine. but I need to hardcode the application.properties path. Is there a way to give inject it dynamically as an argument?

I want to remind again that Spring-boot isnt running as the main container.. I am just using it's libs inside a Java main process so I cant use Spring-boot built-in functionality.

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using Spring Boot to run the process? Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel that Spring Boot already invented?

Comment: I am using vertx as my container(which using the vent loop) I didnt want to embed it into Spring. And I am using Spring for configuration and DI services

Comment: So.. You can still use Spring Boot to bootstrap your code instead of creating an `ApplicationContext` yourself. If you don't include the web stuff it will just start an application context like you would start one, but with all the added benefits .

Comment: So which Sprinig-boot starter lib would you use for that?

Comment: Just the core `spring-boot-starter` that gives you all the core stuff. Then you can use a system param to specify the context (or use profiles) ... Where you now do something like `ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(files)` do `SpringApplication.run(application.class)` and you will get an application context. You can add other starters as well as long as you don't use a web based dependency no web container will be started just a simple application.

Comment: How would you set log4j.properties path in such case?

Comment: That is explained in the Spring Boot documentation.

Comment: I was looking for annotation based configure. if you found any ref that would be very helpfull

Comment: What do you mean with annotation? You just specify the configuration in the properties file that is loaded by Spring. Which file is loaded depends on the startup setting. Nothing annotations in there.

Comment: Can you answer that question with your suggestion?